# php array remove unique array without removing key

Tags: php

I have the following array

This is generated by $product_attribute array

```
Array
(
    [Color] => Array
        (
            [950981-YB051314-01] => Green
            [950981-YB051314-02] => Green
            [950981-YB051314-03] => Green
        )

    [Size] => Array
        (
            [950981-YB051314-01] => M
            [950981-YB051314-02] => L
            [950981-YB051314-03] => XL
        )

)
```

I tried like this

```
<?php foreach($product_attribute as $keys=>$value) { ?>
    <ul class="selections">
    <?php $skus = array(); ?>
    <?php foreach(array_unique($value) as $key => $vals) { ?>
    <?php foreach($value as $key => $val) { ?>
    <?php array_push($skus, $key); ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php $sku = implode(';', array_unique($skus)); ?>
    <li data-sku="<?php echo $keys; ?>"><?php echo rtrim($vals, ','); ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

But the above code produces like

```
<li data-sku="950981-01;950981-02;950981-03">Green</li>
<li data-sku="950981-01;950981-02;950981-03">M</li>
<li data-sku="950981-01;950981-02;950981-03">L</li>
<li data-sku="950981-01;950981-02;950981-03">XL</li>
```

Consider the following as expected output

```
<li data-sku="950981-01;950981-02;950981-03">Green</li>
<li data-sku="950981-01">M</li>
<li data-sku="950981-02">L</li>
<li data-sku="950981-03">XL</li>
```

Can anyone please explain how to handle such case.

Comment: You love using PHP tags, don't you?

Comment: when i execute ur code its getting error ..:p

Comment: i dont know why you have added array_unique($value) ?

Comment: @CodeLover If I am not using array_unique I am getting `Green` three times in my loop

Comment: Actually, i still don't understand op's question. And someone answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue seems like "group keys by value". Do it:

```
$product_attribute = array(
    'color' => array(
        '1' => 'green',
        '2' => 'green',
        '3' => 'green'
    ),

    'size' => array(
       '4' => 'M',
       '5' => 'L',
       '6' => 'XL'
     ),
);


foreach($product_attribute as $param){
    $values = array_unique($param); // fetch unique values -  green,M,L,XL

    foreach($values as $value){
       $keys = array_keys($param,$value); // keys by unique value
       print '<li data-sku="'.implode(';',$keys).'">'.$value.'</li>';
    }
 }

//OUTPUT
<li data-sku="1;2;3">green</li>
<li data-sku="4">M</li>
<li data-sku="5">L</li>
<li data-sku="6">XL</li>
```